# How to make a node call from another node in a package on CONNECT platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When developing a CONNECT package, how can you add a call to another node programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do that via the javascript API:

```js
const platform = require('connect-platform');

platform.call('/your-path', {
  paramA: "some-value",
  //
  // all other parameters you want to pass. if there are none, leave this empty.
  //
});
```

check this guide for more info on that:
https://medium.com/connect-platform/inline-coding-in-connect-platform-534fce3c8cdf